# Erro ao executar gulp --production Vagrant Laravel/Homestead

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, gulp

Configurei um ambiente `laravel/homestead` para estudar o `Laravel 5.1` , ao tentar executar o comando `gulp --production` recebo o erro abaixo:

`Error: Cannot find module 'strip-bom'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/getContents/bufferFile.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)`

Já procurei bastante e não encontrei nada que corrigisse o erro.

Comment: Não sei o que é um ambiente "laravel/homested", um npm install strip-bom não resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro passo:

Delete as pata node_modules recursivamente.

Passo dois:

`sudo npm -g install npm@latest`

Passo três:

`sudo npm install gulp --no-bin-link`